# Loading classpath package name in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm in the middle of converting a project to maven, I redid the project structure to maven standards (src/main/java, etc..) and I have a method to get the test classes to populate the GUI. I'm unable to get the path for the package to search through for an annotation that will return the list of classes. what I had before for the path was
"main/[packageName]" before the project was in the maven structure.

the package is now at src/main/java/[packagename]

here is my method to retrieve the classes with the annotation

```
    private List<Class<?>> getTestClasses(String path) {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(SomeAnnotation.class));

    Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents(path);
    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

    for (BeanDefinition component : components) {
        try {
            Class<?> testClass = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
            classes.add(testClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: nothing should change in this code after migration to maven

Comment: So the old code doesn't work anymore? That's strange... it shouldn't make a difference what directory the source files are in.

Comment: the package is not "src/main/java/[packagename]"  it is just "[packagename]" (i.e. don't include "src/main/java").

Comment: before the change I was sending in main/[package] and it worked fine. I've tried both just "[package]", to no avail.